# Pinning results of Ivy resolution

Tags: java, caching, dependency-management, ivy

So bundler has a notion of `Gemfile.lock` file that will pin the versions of Ruby gems after a successful resolution of dependencies so that subsequent installs by others don't have to go through the resolution process and can just download the exact versions directly. What is the equivalent of this in the Java world? How do I resolve dependencies and then share those resolved dependencies with everyone else and make sure every developer is using the same baseline versions of libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby projects are typically released as source code, downloading  dependencies at install time. This creates a requirement to capture the release's full tree of dependencies.

Java projects, on the other hand, typically release a self contained binary (eg WAR, EAR) containing both software and dependencies. The source code is separate to the binary.

Hopefully this explains why Ivy and Maven do not have a lock file that would be unique to each release of a project.

Comment: This is a fine answer but doesn't really answer my question. Short of rewriting .classpath and other xml files I haven't found a nice way to make sure all dependencies are the same on all developer boxes. If there are + dependencies anywhere then depending on what time people instantiate their project dependencies the results can be wildly different.

Comment: @davidk01 I fully get what you're looking for, but you're not going to get it from either Ivy or Maven. Java developers typically share using binaries, stored in a common Maven repository. It's that shared repository that ensures dependencies are the same on all developer boxes. Not better or worse just different approach.